# Backbone.js - why does my delegateEvents selector not work?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a view that contains nested views of the same type. Because of this, my `delegateEvents` selector needs to be careful to only select the top-level elements and not the elements in the child views.

The following code, used within the context of my view, successfully selects the element I wish to bind:

```
var $link = this.$('> .node > .indent > a'); // success!
```

The `delegateEvents` object, using the same selector, does not hook up the event at all:

```
events: {
    'click > .node > .indent > a': 'toggleGrouped' // fail :(
}
```

Note that I have confirmed that the event hookup does work with other, simpler selectors, so it's not an issue with rendering.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think @darvelo has the best solution here. Just ensure that all your "lower-level" selectors' event listeners call `event.stopPropagation();`. Then those events will never bubble up to reach your top-level View's listeners, and you never need to worry about how to make your selectors so specific as this!

Comment: @Lambart thanks, though you'll note that I asked this question nearly 4 years ago ;)

Comment: I know! But it so happens that I had the same question as you, almost 4 years later. It's still a valid question, and still has valid answers... one of which is *only* a little over 2 years old! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably has to do with jQuery's `delegate` event not liking the `> .node > .indent > a` selector.

You can confirm this by adding the following line of code in your view's render method. (this is what Backbone is doing in `delegateEvents`)

```
$(this.el).delegate('> .node > .indent > a', 'click', this.toggleGrouped);
```

If it still doesn't work then the issue has to do with the `delegate` event and not backbone.

A workaround is to bind to the click event after all the rendering is done in the render method.

```
this.$('> .node > .indent > a').click(this.toggleGrouped);
```

You will also have to bind the context of `toggleGrouped` in the initialize method since it's no longer being automatically bound.

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'toggleGrouped');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. `delegateEvents` uses `jQuery.delegate()`, which for some reason doesn't accept selectors that start with a child descender:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/#comment-66006048

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this I think might be to just take the child selectors `>` out of the `events` hash and in the event handler use `event.stopPropagation()` like so:

```
toggleGrouped: function (evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();

  // event handling code
}
```

The first parent up the chain listening for that event will get it, then prevent it from bubbling up to any others that might have also caught the event.

Comment: Best answer here; it allows the event configuration (and cleanup) to remain simple, using the normal Backbone `events` hash.